# Iterating Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, keras, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to create a Keras [Tokenizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer) out of a single column from hundreds of large CSV files. Dask seems like a good tool for this. My current approach eventually causes memory issues:

```
df = dd.read_csv('data/*.csv', usecol=['MyCol'])

# Process column and get underlying Numpy array.
# This greatly reduces memory consumption, but eventually materializes
# the entire dataset into memory
my_ids = df.MyCol.apply(process_my_col).compute().values

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(my_ids)
```

How can I do this by parts? Something along the lines of:

```
df = pd.read_csv('a-single-file.csv', chunksize=1000)
for chunk in df:
    # Process a chunk at a time
```

Answer (score 2):

Dask DataFrame is technically a set of pandas dataframes, called partitions. When you get the underlying numpy array you are destroying the partitioning structure and it will be one big array. I recommend using `map_partition` function of Dask DataFrames to apply regular pandas functions on each partition separately.

Comment: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend `map_partition` when it suits your problem.  However, if you really just want sequential access, and an API similar to `read_csv(chunksize=...)` then you might be looking for the partitions attribute

```
for part in df.partitions:
    process(model, part.compute())
```